# ngCordova Camera does not open camera but photo album

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-build, ngcordova

I am using exactly [the following example from the offical website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) - thus setting the sourceType to CAMERA and not PHOTOLIBRARY.

```
var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
```

and am testing my app using phonegap build, thus incorporating the following plugin in my config.xml:

**However, when I initiate the code above, then in my app it opens my Phone Albums - thus forcing me to select an image instead of taking a picture. What is going on?**

Comment: did you build your code after using these options? may be you need something like phonegap build ios or phonegap build android

Answer (score 0):

For camera, you can try like this one

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 100,
    targetHeight: 100,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}, function(err) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I tried, but it still does not access my Camera but my Phone Albums...